# UIView drawRect vs initWithFrame

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView which has several buttons added to it as subviews. Currently I have the buttons in drawRect:, which I have heard is a bad idea because drawRect can be called several times. I tried to move these UIButtons to initWithFrame, but they just don't get drawn. How should I fix this?

I am not using interface builder, so there are no NIB files present. The initWithFrame is called. I checked by adding an NSLog(...), and my NSMutableArrays are being properly initialized.

My initWitFrame: code currently has very little. It is

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        inputs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy"];
        renc =[[RenameController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have tried to add a textlabel like the following

```
#define BOX_WIDTH 155.0
#define BOX_OFFSET 45.00
#define ROW_HEIGHT 27

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        inputs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy"];
        renc =[[RenameController alloc] init];

        double row=0.0;
        [self makelabel:@"Start" at:CGRectMake(0, row, BOX_OFFSET, ROW_HEIGHT)];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) makelabel:(NSString *) str at:(CGRect) rect
{
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    title.text = str;
    title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [self addSubview:title];
    [title release];
}
```

Comment: OK, then can your share your initWithFrame: Code? Is initWithFrame: called?

Comment: Added the code. I don't think it's that useful though

Comment: This code doesn't show any buttons being created or added to the view.  Could you post the code where you attempted to add them to the view in -initWithFrame:?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@tonklon is spot on. Additionally, the usual pattern is to have your custom initialization code in a third method, such as `-sharedInit`, which is called after the appropriate `super` initializer:

```
- (id)sharedInit {
    // do whatever, possibly releasing self on error and returning nil
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [self sharedInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithDecoder: aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self = [self sharedInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet the view is loaded from a nib file? Just use the same code to add your subviews in initWithCoder:

UIView Class Reference:

> If you use Interface Builder to design
>   your interface, this method is not
>   called when your view objects are
>   subsequently loaded from the nib file.
>   Objects in a nib file are
>   reconstituted and then initialized
>   using their initWithCoder: method,
>   which modifies the attributes of the
>   view to match the attributes stored in
>   the nib file. For detailed information
>   about how views are loaded from a nib
>   file, see Resource Programming Guide.

Comment: Sorry, no interface builder in this house!