# iOS - Sub classed UIButton - Where to add code for highlighted state?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I want to have my buttons in my iOS app to have a red gradient. At first I was using images to do this, but then realised I can do it with QuartzCore framework. I have the following implementation file:

```
#import "RedButton.h"

@implementation RedButton

@synthesize gradientLayer = _gradientLAyer;

- (void)awakeFromNib;
{
    // Initialize the gradient layer
    self.gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    // Set its bounds to be the same of its parent
    [self.gradientLayer setBounds:[self bounds]];
    // Center the layer inside the parent layer
    [self.gradientLayer setPosition:
     CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width/2,
                 [self bounds].size.height/2)];

    // Insert the layer at position zero to make sure the 
    // text of the button is not obscured
    [[self layer] insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    // Set the layer's corner radius
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    // Turn on masking
    [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    // Display a border around the button 
    // with a 1.0 pixel width
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(158.0f/255.0f) green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];

    [self.gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:(214.0f/255.0f) green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor], 
                               (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:(141.0f/255.0f) green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor], nil]];

    [[self layer] setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Release our gradient layer
    self.gradientLayer = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

First question - am I right to use awakeFromNib here? Or should I be using initWithFrame?

Second question - originally I was using images and using interface builder to set the default and highlighted states of the button. Now that I'm not using images, how can I set the appearance of the button to change when it's highlighted? I just want to reverse the gradient.

Third question - I've seen it written in some places that you shouldn't subclass UIButton. If not, how would I change all my buttons to have this gradient without duplicating a lot of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit1:** Misread the part about images. 
You should be able to do something like this to set the button states natively as image using your gradients

```
// your code for setting up the gradient layer comes first
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, [self bounds].size.height));
[gradientLayer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *bgImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self setBackGroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateWhatever] // replace with correct states
```

============================

I recommend putting your initialization code in a function other than `awakeFromNib` (for the case where the button is actually NOT being used in a nib but possibly being created in code). You should create a custom initialization function and call it in both `initWithCoder` and `initWithFrame` [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367685/uiview-drawrect-vs-initwithframe) shows a pretty good pattern for doing so.

You can set the background for different states in your initialization by calling

```
[self setBackGroundImage: forState];
```

Where in this case your state would be `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

That aside, one argument against subclassing in this situation is that you're not actually defining any custom behavior, you're just trying to reuse some styling code. A subclass isn't necessary here and you can do something as simple as creating a formatting function somewhere (in your viewcontroller maybe, or some function in another class) that takes a UIButton as a scenario and performs all of that initialization code on it. This way, you will not have your buttons locked up in a subclass (which is useful if you actually end up using another UIButton subclass.. I for example like to use one that defines custom touch behavior allowing the button to be a non-rectangular shape (and have its touch area limited as such).

Another argument I've seen is that UIButton contains some factory functions that may return a button of a different type than your subclass, but you may never run into this issue if you don't use those functions.